# Workbox will not load

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I'm trying to use Workbox to add PWA functionality to my website. I'm following the [Get Started](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/get-started) guide, but I'm not getting far. When I run the website in Chrome I get the following error:

```
Refused to load the script 'https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/3.6.1/workbox-sw.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'".
```

Per the docs, I am importing workbox-sw.js in my service worker file that is in my wwwroot folder with the following line:

```
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/3.6.1/workbox-sw.js');
```

The "Refused to load..." error occurs on that import statement.

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: show how u req/load that tag-uri ??

Answer (score 4):

You have a [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) configuration that prevents loading scripts from third-party origins and then you are trying to load a script from Google. You either need to allow the script to load or load the page from your site.

1. [Update the CSP header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP#Example_2) to allow the Google domain by adding `script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://storage.googleapis.com`.
2. [Using Local Workbox Files Instead of CDN](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-sw#using_local_workbox_files_instead_of_cdn)