# How to configure Workbox in Create-React-App based app?

Tags: webpack, service-worker, create-react-app

I am using Create-React-App (CRA) which registers service workers by default (using [workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-sw)), and would like to leave them enabled if possible. However I absolutely can't allow my app to load any external sources - but Workbox in CRA by default loads `workbox-sw.js` from Google CDN (as seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53234212/workbox-will-not-load)).

Currently I am using [Content Security Policy headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) to make sure the request is blocked, but this of course results in error message being recorded, and I might as well not register service workers at all.

How do I configure my app to only use **local** JS, preferably without ejecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find a proper solution for this, so I ended up using two mechanisms to achieve a similar effect:

1. CI build script replaces the reference to Google CDN with a local URL:

```
sed -i -e 's#https://storage[.]googleapis[.]com/workbox-cdn/releases/[0-9.]*/workbox-sw.js#/workbox/workbox-sw.js#g' build/service-worker.js
```

2. to make sure that this will never be bypassed, I also set [Content Security Policy headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) (and also meta tags, in case app is hosted somewhere where the headers can't be easily set), so that browser knows that my app can't access Google CDN (or anything else really, with a few exceptions that are under my control).

The first part of the solution is a bit ugly and I would still be interested in a better way, but this is the best method I could find without ejecting CRA.

Comment: I am curious if this is what the general React community would recommend? I would think that CRA would provide a more elegant solution for bundling the Workbox library within my JS bundle...

Answer (score 1):

Using Local Workbox Files Instead of CDN
If you don’t want to use the CDN, it’s easy enough to switch to Workbox files hosted on your own domain.

The simplest approach is to get the files via workbox-cli's copyLibraries command or from a GitHub Release, and then tell workbox-sw where to find these files via the modulePathPrefix config option.

If you put the files under ***/third_party/workbox/***, you would use them like so:

```
importScripts('/third_party/workbox/workbox-sw.js');

workbox.setConfig({
modulePathPrefix: '/third_party/workbox/'
});
```

With this, you’ll use only the local Workbox files.

fore reference https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-sw#using_local_workbox_files_instead_of_cdn

Comment: @sancelot Thank you, but - where do I put this? package.json, registerServiceWorker.js, or somewhere else? I don't see any reference to `workbox` in any of the files I could edit in Create-React-App... Am I missing something?

Comment: This thread explains it https://medium.com/la-creativer%C3%ADa/using-workbox-with-create-react-app-without-ejecting-b02b804854b

Comment: @sancelot I don't think that thread explains it sufficiently. Could someone post an answer to this in Stackoverflow itself? thank you!